# Scipy - how can I change leaf font size (leaf_font_size doesn't work)?

Tags: python, scipy, dendrogram

I would like to draw a dendrogram with bigger fontsize, but the command for this in the [scipy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram.html) isn't working. The size of the label is the same with leaf_font_size=8. / 24. / None. Maybe there is something I haven't understood well about the usage of this, or you know some tricks to make it work. I would appreciate if you could help me.
My code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.cluster import hierarchy as hier
import cPickle
from abclib import *



np.set_printoptions(precision=5, suppress=True)
df = pd.read_excel('rmsd_a2a_matrix.xlsx')
Z = hier.linkage(df, 'ward')
ABC = cPickle.load(open('ABC.pkl', 'rb'))
labelL = []
for i in list(df.columns.values):
    for abc in ABC.values():
        if i == abc.pdb.pdbid:
            labelL.append('%s (%s)' % (i, abc.name))


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 20))
plt.title('Dendrogram')
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.set_ylabel('pdb id and name')
ax.set_xlabel('distance')
ax.yaxis.set_label_position("right")
den = hier.dendrogram(
    Z,
    #leaf_rotation=30.,  # rotates the x axis labels - I don't use this
    leaf_font_size=24.,  # font size for the x axis labels
    labels = labelL,
    orientation = 'right'
)


plt.savefig('dendogram.png', bbox_inches='tight', transparent = True, dpi = 300)
plt.close()
```

Comment: Which version of scipy are you using?  You can check with `import scipy; print(scipy.__version__)`  There were several fixes to the dendrogram label formatting in scipy 0.17.0.

Comment: 0.14.1
I checked if it works with default orientation and it does. I will try to update scipy, then.

Comment: It works with the new version. Thank you!